# How install SwissRanger?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, i'm starting using ROS, and I need to install the drivers for SwissRanger, but i don't know who?

This link doesn't have the link to download the drivers:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/swissranger_camera

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9784/how-install-swissranger?/) by [Alberto Rivera](https://answers.ros.org/users/449/alberto-rivera/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Take a look at the [Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/swissranger_camera/Tutorials/Download%20and%20install%20swissranger_camera), it goes through all the steps of setting up the driver.

As a quick note, most ROS stacks don't have a download link - you're going to be expected to download the source (via svn or hg or git) and compile (or cross-compile) it to your particular system.

---

Originally posted by [rbtying](https://answers.ros.org/users/285/rbtying/) with karma: 73 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2